# how to apply click on image map ( android )

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have one image with multi action 
iwanna to know how to make an onclick in specific coordinate

like map on html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom `OnTouchListener`.  Here is an example:

```
yourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
   {
      if(event.getAction() == case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        int positionX = event.getX();
        int positionY = event.getY();
        // do something based on position of touch

        return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: please can u wirte the whole code ? , 
what i will write in "// do something based on position of touch" and how to define "yourimageview" because it gives error , the error gone away when i write this line " View yourImageView =  findViewById(R.id.footer1); " > i don't know if this correct